# Using father scope variables in angular.js

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am new to angular.js and I am trying to understand something.

Let's say I have a DB of companies and employees and I am creating a structure to retrieve all the companies and the employees in the first page (index.html - I am using the:

```
$routeProvider.when('/index', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/companies-list.html',
      controller: 'AppCtrl'
    })
```

In this controller I fetch from DB all the companies.

On click on one of the companies I am routing to another view with another controller:

```
.when('/group/:id', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/company-employees.html',
      controller: 'CompanyEmployeesInfo'
    })
```

I already have all the data I need in the AppCtrl about the company and I don't want to fetch it again from DB.

Is it possible to use Data from another scope, or pass the data so I won't need to bring it again from my servers?

I really appreciate your help,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in the `$rootScope` - this will be available "globally"

Answer (score 0):

You can create a service which serves as a State - Manager, which stores the data of the particular company into something like current_company. This can be an array or JSON, of your choice.

Remember this would happen just before you route to the employees page.

In 'CompanyEmployeesInfo' you just need to access the get method of this service to retrieve the information of the current company selected.

Please Note: The set and get methods will have to be explicitly defined and returned from the service.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how can I run the Service just before I do the routing?